# CMake include errors (file not found, undefined reference)

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm creating a project that makes use of CMake.

I have an `include` folder for headers and an `src` folder for source code. When attempting to build the project with `cmake --build .`, I get an `"undefined reference"` error:

```
/sdcard/dev/cpp/Bedrock++/src/main.cpp:(.text+0x70): undefined 
reference to `ChatFormat::Blue'
```

Additional detail below:

```
$ cmake --build .
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /sdcard/dev/cpp/Bedrock++
Scanning dependencies of target Bedrock++
[ 33%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Bedrock++.dir/Server.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Bedrock++.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable Bedrock++
CMakeFiles/Bedrock++.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/sdcard/dev/cpp/Bedrock++/src/main.cpp:(.text+0x70): undefined 
reference to `ChatFormat::Blue'
clang-5.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/Bedrock++.dir/build.make:121: 
src/Bedrock++] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:86: 
src/CMakeFiles/Bedrock++.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

Project root `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7)

# Build all dependent libraries as static

project(Bedrock++)

#add_subdirectory(lib/json)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(include)
```

`src/CMakeLists.txt`

```
project(bedrock++)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")

file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
```

`include/CMakeLists.txt`

```
install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}" FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "util/ChatFormat.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World! " << ChatFormat::Blue << "hey" << std::endl;
}
```

The `ChatFormat.h` header is found in `include/util/ChatFormat.h` and contains the following for every different colour:

```
static const std::string Black;
```

I've attempted to solve the problem myself to no avail with hours of research on the internet proving to be a dead end. I hope I didn't miss something obvious.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the full text of the linker error ("Undefined reference") which you're getting (i.e. which reference is undefined?), and also the full declaration of `Blue` (including any containing namespace/class) in `ChatFormat,h`. It's hard to answer a question without having all the data, and you should make sure your questions always contain a [mcve].

Comment: @Angew Blue is the same as Black, except it has a different number in quotes (which shouldnt make any difference). I'll uldate it with the error

Comment: You've shown the definition of `Black` in the `.cpp` file, but I was asking you to also show its declaration in the `.h`.

Comment: @Angew I updated the question

Comment: That update cannot be right, since you're accessing it as `ChatFormat::Blue` and the compiler is not complaining, but you've not shown any `ChatFormat` context around the declaration. Please provide **accurate** info if you want help. See my earlier comment: "including any containing namespace/class"

Comment: Absolutely a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CMake output suggests that 'ChatFormat.cpp', which contains the definition of 'ChatFormat::Black', is not being compiled. Only 'Server.cpp' and 'main.cpp' are being compiled.

I'm guessing that 'ChatFormat.cpp', like it's corresponding header, is under a 'utils' directory? But the GLOB command you are using to find your source files will only be finding files name *.cpp in the root folder. You might want to try changing 'GLOB' to 'GLOB_RECURSE' so it will pick up files in subfolders, though it is generally recommended that you avoid using globbing entirely and list each source file explicitly...

Answer (score 1):

## Header inclusion error

The problem with "Header file not found" is that your `src/CMakeLists.txt` contains a `project()` command. That declares a new CMake project (think Visual Studio *solution*) for that subtree. `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` will therefore refer to that project's source directory within that subtree. In other words, your `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include` resolves to `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/include`.

Based on your CMake file structure, I'd say it makes no sense for `src/CMakeLists.txt` to contain a `project()` command. Just remove it, and include paths should start working for you.

## Unresolved reference error

The question doesn't contain enough information to solve this, but my hunch is you're somehow messing up internal linkage (`static`) and definition in a dedicated source file. These normally don't mesh at all. You might want to read through the canonical [Undefined Reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/1782465) here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the first solution :) For the second one i copied off https://github.com/cuberite/cuberite/blob/e1d3b201bd7a22f2924182f0243bb51433080c79/src/ChatColor.cpp and https://github.com/cuberite/cuberite/blob/e1d3b201bd7a22f2924182f0243bb51433080c79/src/ChatColor.h which seems to work there but not for me. Don't forget i mentioned that it worked before then i started changing directorh structure and stuff and it stopped working. Weird.

Comment: @TheDiamondYT BTW, since you're using the *heavily discouraged* `file(GLOB)` to get your source file list: are you sure that `ChatFormat.cpp` is part of your source list? Is it on the same directory level as `main.cpp`?

Comment: Oh wow. No it's not. How would i look for files in all directories then?

Comment: @TheDiamondYT Follow [CMake's advice](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html) in the (`file(GLOB)` section) and list all files manually (you can dedicate a file to setting a variable and `include()` that file if you don't want to pollute your CMakeList). You'll save yourself a lot of trouble